$L^{\infty}$ estimate for the sum of homogeneous Littlewood-Paley block
I meet a problem when reading Fourier Analysis and Nonlinear Partial Differential Equations written by Bahouri, Chemin & Danchin. On page 87 the authors are trying to proof the following theorem:
Thm: There exists a constant $C$ such that for any real number $s$ and any $(p,r)$ in $[1,\infty]^2$, we have, for any $(u,v)$ in $L^{\infty}\times\dot{B}^s_{p,r}$,
$$
\|\dot{T}_uv\|_{\dot{B}_{p,r}^s}\le C^{1+|s|}\|u\|_{L^{\infty}}\|v\|_{\dot{B}_{p,r}^s}.
$$
In proof they use Lemma 2.1(Bernstein-type lemma) to prove the following estimate:
$$
\|\dot{S}_{j-1}u\|_{L^{\infty}}\le C\|u\|_{L^{\infty}}.
$$
where $\dot{S}_ju=\sum_{j'\le j-1}\dot{\Delta}_{j'}u$, $\dot{\Delta}_ju=\varphi(2^{-j}D)u$, $\varphi$ is a smooth radial function supported in the ring $\mathcal{C}=(3/4\le|x|\le8/3)$, taking values in the interval $[0,1]$.
My problem is that I don't know how to use Bernstein-type lemma (or lemma 2.2 on $\sigma(D)$) to prove this estimate. It seems that neither $L^p$ estimate of $D^ku$ mentioned in the Bernstein-type lemma nor $L^p$ estimate of $\sigma(D)u$ mentioned in lemma 2.2 can derive $L^{\infty}$ estimate of $\dot{S}_{j-1}u$ (since $\varphi$ isn't a homogeneous function like $\sigma$). I've tried to use Young's inequality but I also met a problem: using the convolution form of $\dot{\Delta}_ju$ we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\|\dot{S}_ju\|_{L^{\infty}}&\le\sum_{j'\le j-1}2^{j'd}\|\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}h(2^{j'}y)u(x-y)dy\|_{L^{\infty}}\\
&\le\sum_{j'\le j-1}2^{j'd}\|h(2^{j'}\cdot)\|_{L^1}\|u\|_{L^{\infty}}\\
&=\sum_{j'\le j-1}\|h\|_{L^1}\|u\|_{L^{\infty}}
\end{aligned}
$$
where $h=\mathcal{F}^{-1}\varphi$, $d$ is dimension. For every fixed $j$, this is of course a $L^{\infty}$ estimate, but the estimate in book and the theorem itself seems to ask the constant $C$ shouldn't rely on $j$. When $j\rightarrow+\infty$, the estimate I got above obviously tends to $\infty$. How should I modify this process?
